# How to hide certain set of WPF controls showing up in Visual Studio Toolbox?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio-2010

The ToolboxItem(false) works for Winforms controls.
ToolboxBrowsable(false) does not work for the WPF controls.

```
[ToolboxBrowsable(false)]
public class MyControl : UserControl
{

}
```

The MyControl even with ToolboxBrowsable(false) shows up in the Visual Studio toolbox.

What am I doing wrong?

-Datte

Answer (score 0):

The `[ToolboxBrowsable(false)]` attribute does not have any effect within the same solution.
This is because you might want to be able to use the control in any forms within that solution.
If you compile the class library, remove it from the solution and add a reference to it you should see the control disappearing from the toolbox.

Comment: How do you reference the control in your project?

Comment: The project that uses the my WPF controls and the project with WPF controls are NOT in the same solution.